# Meaning of delta-u term in variational derivative

Tags: calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative

I am considering a question in the calculus of variations. I can understand the concept of the variational derivative, but I am not sure what the $\delta u$ in this question means:

"6. Let $Ω⊆R^n$ be a connected and relatively compact open set with smooth boundary. In this problem we study the gradient flow of the functional
$$J[u]=∫_{Ω} {\frac{1}{2}|∇u|^2+F(u)}dVol$$
where $F(u)= \frac{1}{4} (u^2-1)^2$, subject to the mean-zero constraint
$$∫_{Ω}u(x,t)dVol(x) =0 \space ∀t$$
We will show, following [2] and [3], that accomodating the mean-zero constraint requires modifying the duality pairing you used to define the variational derivative in class.
Compute the variational derivative of J[u] using the expression from the lecture notes:
$$⟨δJ/δu,δu⟩_{L^2}=DJ(u)∙δu \space ∀δu∈C_{c}^∞ (Ω)$$
where DJ(u) denotes the Fréchet derivative of J[u] at u. Explain why the gradient flow
$$u_t=-δJ/δu$$
does not in general satisfy the mean-zero constraint, even if u satisfies a homogeneous Neumann condition. Do you recognize the gradient flow PDE?"

Comment: It's just any test function